# Interface Static Methods on Nested Class

Tags: java, class, interface

I just learned today just a few minutes ago that I can nest a number of static classes within a containing class which I wasn't aware of. I got used with creating classes with no nested classes at all in the past.

I thought that making use of nested classes will help in readability of codes especially when an object or a class has subclasses or types, just like Payment where you need to consider paymentterms.

I find that understanding nested classes and applying it to my coding is very powerful combined with interfaces.

So I tried to apply it to my current project where I design the classes and methods of Payment.

```
public class Payment {

    public static class terms{

        public static class monthly implements Monthly{

            @Override //error here
            public static void setDownpayment(double aDownPayment) //and error here
            {

            }

        }

        public static class quarterly{
            public static void setDownpayment(){
                //do something
            }
        }

        public static class semestral{
            public static void setDownpayment(){
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the interface I created

```
public interface Monthly {
    public void setDownpayment(double aDownPayment);
}
```

I tried to make the `setDownpayment()` method to be `static` so I can refer to it like this:

```
Payment.terms.monthly.setDownpayment(aDecimalValue);
```

But it doesn't seem to allow static methods. because there's an error on the 2 lines I commented with "`//error here` and `//and error here`"

How do I fix it?

Any other possible solution or alternative ways or design suggestions?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: First thing that jumps out: you cannot override static methods.

Comment: A litte off-topic from your question, but you might consider the issue of [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: which version of Java do you use?

Comment: Names of Java classes should alwas start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: Maybe it's just unfortunate naming, but I do not understand the interface `Monthly`. An interface should be an abstract description of features that are common to concrete instances. I do not see sense in creating an interface `Monthly` as I don't see any more concrete options.

Answer (score 2):

In java, You have to *override* all methods of an implemented **Interface**, and as **static** methods are part of classes not Objects and they are not overridable that's why ***static methods inside interfaces are not allowed*** (for before java8 ).

In Java8, *static method in Interface is allowed but they must have body inside the interface and you can't override them inside the implementation classes*.